# Converting to String with StringFormat

Tags: c#

I would like to write a `ToString()` method for a generic class where I can specify a StringFormat.

So far, I have the following code:

```
public class Foo<T> : IFoo
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    string IFoo.Value { get { ValueToString(Value); } }

    public string StringFormat { get; set }

    public Foo(T value, string stringFormat)
    {
        Value = value;
        StringFormat = stringFormat;
    }

    private string ValueToString(T value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringFormat))
        {
            var formattable = value as IFormattable;
            if (formattable != null)
            {
                var format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.GetFormat(typeof(T)) as IFormatProvider;
                if (format != null)
                    return formattable.ToString(StringFormat, format);
            }
        }

        return Convert.ToString(value);
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    string Value { get; }
}
```

I am calling the code like this:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar()
    {
        var dateTimeFoo = new Foo<DateTime>(DateTime.Now, "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var iFoo = dateTimeFoo as IFoo;
        if (Convert.ToString(dateTimeFoo.Value) != iFoo.Value)
        {
            //stringformat worked...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with my current implementation is this line of code:

```
var format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.GetFormat(typeof(T)) as IFormatProvider;
```

It returns `null` and it should return `null` for objects that don't have a `FormatProvider` but `DateTime` certainly has the ability, how can I get the correct `FormatProvider` of a generic `T`?

Comment: `DateTime` is `IFormattable` but it is not an `IFormatProvider`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CultureInfo` already implements `IFormatProvider`, all you want to do is

```
return formattable.ToString(StringFormat, CulturuInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

If you look at the implementation of `GetFormat` method

```
public virtual Object GetFormat(Type formatType)
{
    if (formatType == typeof (NumberFormatInfo))
    {
        return (NumberFormat);
    }
    if (formatType == typeof (DateTimeFormatInfo))
    {
        return (DateTimeFormat);
    }
    return (null);
}
```

You can see it only supports two types and returns *null* otherwise [as documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

CultureInfo already is an IFormatProvider, I don't see why you would need to get the specific part here.

```
var formattable = value as IFormattable;
if (formattable != null)
{
    //var format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.GetFormat(typeof(T)) as IFormatProvider;
    //if (format != null)
        return formattable.ToString(StringFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Comment: And what is StringFormat? I mean, if you have currency with group separator, decimal separator etc, how do I define it? For a date, it is easy, I am getting a string format pattern. But for decimal and currency I am getting tons of properties. How can I use that easily?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getformat(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> CultureInfo.GetFormat() method only supports the **NumberFormatInfo** and > **DateTimeFormatInfo** types.

You're passing the `DateTime` type, so the method returns `null`. So, the correct way to obtain the format is:

```
object format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.GetFormat(typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo));
```

or

```
object format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo));
```

Depending on de type of T.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `CultureInfo.GetFormat`

Return Value
Type: System.Object

The value of the NumberFormat property, [...], if formatType is the Type object for the NumberFormatInfo class.

-or-

The value of the DateTimeFormat property, [...], if formatType is the Type object for the DateTimeFormatInfo class.

-or-

null, if formatType is any other object.

So you can't use this method for an arbitrary type.